# How to load an es6 module in an html page on the load event

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am new to ES6 modules, please could you let me know how I can import a function from an ES6 module on a web-page and then use that function on a click event on a button.

So far I have defined this module in a file called (ES6Part3Module.js):

```
export function sayHello() {
return "hi there folks";
}
```

Then in my html page I have loaded the module in this way:

```
`<script src="ES6Part3Module.js" type="module"`>`</script`>
```

I now want some way of creating a click handler for a button on the page:

```
`<button id="sayHelloButton"`>Say Hello`</click`>
```

which calls the sayHello() function from my ES6 module.

I have tried creating a local (module) script on my page:

```
`<script type="module"`>
import sayHello from "ES6Part3Module.js";
window.hello = sayHello;
`</script`>
```

and then having some jquery on the page which runs on load:

```
$( function() {

$("#sayHelloButton").click(function() {
alert(hello());
});

});
```

But when the button on the html page is clicked, I get an error, saying that hello is not defined.

Please could you let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using an old version of system.js. I would be interested in an answer using the new version of system.js.

```
<!--
ref (https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/angular-2-development-with-typescript/chapter-2/159, p 159, listing2.7)
-->
<!--unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm-->
<script src="//unpkg.com/es6-promise@3.0.2/dist/es6-promise.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/traceur@0.0.111/bin/traceur.js"></script>
<!--system js, version that was released in 21/08/2016-->
<script src="//unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.37/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
System.import('./ES6Part3Module.js').then(ES6Part3Module => {
  window.hello = ES6Part3Module.sayHello;
});
</script>

<script>
$( function() {

$("#sayHelloButton").click(function() {
alert(hello());
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you were actually very close to the solution.
after you set`window.hello=sayHello;` (which you can do inside your module, you don't need an inline module to do so), you just set the button's click event to window.hello (instead of just hello), you don't even need to use JQuery for that, you can just do:

```
<button onclick="window.hello()">Say Hello</button>
```